# text clip mask but invert where there is no overlapping background. CSS

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I'm building out a CSS style for designers portfolio and he has designed a clip mask for text that overlaps with a clip mask for a background image design.

Where the two masks overlap I need the text to change back to white and no be a clip mask....

any idea how to achieve this?
Please see the image for more detail.

I'm hoping to use an only CSS solution but that might be too much to ask.

thanks for you help.

I'm thinking if there is anyway to change the "Invert" settings or have two clip-masks that can cancel each other out?

common dunk on me.

Comment: Hi please include your code in your question.